# Regular expression for email in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, regex, validation

There are a lot of question on stack overflow possibly for regular expression for email. I assume I will not get taged as duplicate question...:)

Currently I am using regular expression for email address:

```
\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*
```

This works fine with following:
 xyz@gmail.com

What I want to allowed here user can give space at begining or at ending and possibly both for instance: "     nihantanu@gmail.com      " I want to pass it by regular expression Currently it's giving Invalid I believe it should be.

What I tried `^[ \t]+|[ \t]+$ + \w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*`

But It's not working I am not more familiar with how to write regular expression. Currently I m trying to learn from Here http://www.regular-expressions.info/examples.html.

Comment: Here on Stackoverflow you can find thousands of similar questions. And millions in Google. Just try :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `\s*\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*\s*`.